# SharePoint 2010 database backup and restore on a development environment

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

For the purpose of checking the integrity of backup, I configured a SharePoint 2010 development environment on a Windows 7 machine.
I had taken content database backup of my production farm using the SQL Server Management Studio backup option.

These are the steps I followed on my Windows 7 machine -

1. I copied the .bak file to my development environment.
2. Restored the copied database backup using SQL Server Management Studio "Restore" option by restoring it into a new database.
3. Created a new Web Application using Central Administration.
4. Removed the current database of the newly created Web Application by using Central Administration -> Application Management -> Manage Content Databases
5. Verified the Content Database using this command -

   ```
   Test-SPContentDatabase -Name restorethisdb -WebApplication http://ip:port
   ```
6. Added the restored database to my new Web Application using command -

   ```
   stsadm .exe-o addcontentdb -url http://ip:port -databasename restorethisdb
   ```

Now, these are the problems and doubts that I have -

1. I cannot access the restored Web Application on my development environment if I do not know the url of the web application on my production environment.
   For example: If the url of web app on my prod env is `http://ipprod:port1/sites/abc/testingsite.aspx` 
   I can only access the restored web app if I access it using the url `http://ip:port/sites/abc/testingsite.aspx` 
   (PS - ip:port is ip and port of the development environment.)
2. I cannot access the restored web app on dev env using `http://localhost/sites/abc/testingsite.aspx` but i can access it using `http://ip:port/sites/abc/testingsite.aspx`

I would be very glad if somebody can help me in clearing my concepts. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is your alternate access mapping looks for the web application? Do you have Ip and port number there or server name port number? Also on what port u configured web application?

Comment: it is http://<computer-name>:port.   The port was auto generated.

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen such behaviour.

I suspect the web application you created in Dev is set up on that port. You can check this in Central Administration website.

Comment: I can access the website using either http://<computer-name>:port or http://<ip address>:port. Anyway, I'm more concerned about point 1 - i.e. if i do not know the exact url of the site whose backup i restored then i'm not able to access the restored site.